# garbage collector and closure

Tags: garbage-collection, closures

Since garbage collection is a feature of JavaScript that collects all undesired values, it raises the question why garbage is not collected when closure is used.
The code that explains why the given code does not collect var a = 7 in JavaScript is provided below.

`function x() {   var a = 7;     function y() {     console.log(a);   }   return y; } var z = x(); console.log(z); z();`

I am expecting that garbage collector and closure will work here together.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that return of function *x* (that is function *y*) depends on *a*. Since *y* is assigned to *z*, garbage collector cannot collect it for now, so it also cannot collect *a*. If *a* was collected, what would *y* console.log()?

For more info consult [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Also note, that using *var* is not recommended. Use *let* or *const* instead.